# Run R code selections in VSCode Jupyter Extension Interactive window

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, rlang, jupyter-irkernel

The VS Code Interactive Window now supports arbitrary Jupyter kernels (yay!), but I can't figure out how to send code to the Interactive Window from a non-Python plaintext file (e.g., an `.R` file) the way you can with `shift+enter` for Python (with the appropriate settings changes).